Как отсортировать по возрастанию значения оси Y у второго графика Plotly?

Как отсортировать по возрастанию значения оси Y у второго графика Plotly (volume)?
df = {
        'open': candles_open,
        'close': candles_close,
        'high': candles_high,
        'low': candles_low,
        'volume': candles_volume,
        'begin': candles_begin,
        'end': candles_end,
    }
    fig = make_subplots(
        rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.05, row_width=[0.2, 0.7]
    )
    fig_candles = go.Candlestick(
            x=df['begin'],
            open=df['open'],
            high=df['high'],
            low=df['low'],
            close=df['close'],
        )
    fig_volume = go.Bar(x=df['begin'], y=df['volume'], showlegend=False)
    fig.add_trace(fig_candles, row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(fig_volume, row=2, col=1)
    fig.update(layout_xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
    fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor="#d1d7dd", paper_bgcolor="#d1d7dd", yaxis={'categoryorder':'total ascending'})


    self.ui.webEngineView.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn',
                                              config={
                                                  'modeBarButtonsToAdd': [
                                                      'drawline',
                                                      'drawopenpath',
                                                      'drawclosedpath',
                                                      'drawcircle',
                                                      'drawrect',
                                                      'eraseshape'
                                                  ]}))
    self.ui.tabWidget.setTabEnabled(2, True)


а вы не пробовали отсортировать df["volume"] перед тем, как строить по нему график volume? plotly отрисовывает значения по порядку их нахождения в  датафрейме. с другой стороны, вы можете потерять сортировку по дате.

поменял местами add_trace - результат тот же самый, volum только цвет на синий поменял..

я, вроде бы, советовал отсортировать датафрейм, а не менять что-то местами.
